# asp.net custom Gridview which switch to edit mode only for clicked cell

Tags: asp.net, gridview, custom-controls

I am trying to create custom GridView server control as i want to go to edit mode only to the selected cell.this is my code but it does not work

```
  protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow r in this.Rows)
        {
            if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
           {
                for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < r.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
                {
        r.Cells[columnIndex].Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this, "Edit$" + r.Cells[columnIndex], true);

                }
           }
        }
        base.Render(writer);  

    }
```

can anybody help pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a Gridview will only allow you to edit a row at a time.  And it's an all or nothing deal for each row, assuming of course that none of your columns are marked `ReadOnly`.

Secondly, the edit event itself is row based not cell based so to get the functionality you want you're going to have to create your own update routine that moves through each cell of each row and update your data store accordingly

> I want to say that just because you ***can*** do something doesn't
>   necessarily mean you ***should***.  This is a complete abomination of
>   a very widely used control.  So, that said, the fact that we can do
>   this is, IMO, a testament to the control designers.

In the designer for the Gridview, convert all editable fields to template fields and DO NOT add any Selection/Edit/Update/Delete/Insert command controls. These are Row based actions and you want to avoid this, especially Edit. You're going to have to write your own routine - see above

Then change to Source view (it's easier to do this next part from the here)

1. delete the contents of the `<ItemTemplate>`'s
2. move the contents of the `<EditItemTemplate>`s to the `<ItemTemplate>`
3. delete all the `<EditItemTemplate>`'s - they're unnecessary at this point
4. Make each editable control ReadOnly, ie: **`<asp:TextBox ID="tbxWhatever" runat="server" Text='Bind("some_field_name")' ReadOnly="True"`**

Now what you've done above is move the Edit mode controls to what is normally the ReadOnly portion of the GridView.  Feel free to change or use whatever controls suit your purpose.

To get the functionality you want you need to add a js event handler that enables the control.  I suggest adding an `onclick` handler to each editible control via `RowCreated` event, something like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxWhatever" runat="server" Text='Bind("some_field_name")' 
        Enabled="False" 
        onclick="EnableMe(this)"
```

Code Behind (VB) :

```
Private Sub Gridview1_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Gridview1.RowCreated
    dim gv as GridView = sender
    dim tbx as TextBox = gv.FindControl("tbxWhatever")
    tbx.Attributes.Add("onclick", "EnableMe(this);")
End Sub
```

In some `<script>` tag or associated `.js` code file lives this:

```
function EnableMe( elem ) {
  elem.readOnly= (! elem.readOnly);
}
```

And lastly someplace on your page your going to have to place a save button.  If you use a standard Button or ImageButton you should be fine.  Set the `CommandName` argument to something suitable and handle the button's `Command` event in the code behind.  This is where you execute your custom save routine.

Good Luck.

*PS: Regarding your desire to create some derived version of a GridView that operates at a cell level, what you want is more like a Spreadsheet or DataGrid than an asp:Gridview.  You may want to find a better starting point.*